# Is the wedge product of top forms zero?

Tags: differential-geometry, differential-forms

1. Let's take $\omega, \tau \in \Omega^n\mathbb R^n$. I think $\omega=fdx^1 \wedge ... \wedge dx^n$ and $\tau=gdx^1 \wedge ... \wedge dx^n$ for some $f,g \in C^{\infty}(\mathbb R^n)$. Then $$\omega \wedge \tau =  fg dx^1 \wedge ... \wedge dx^n \wedge dx^1 \wedge ... \wedge dx^n$$ Is $dx^1 \wedge ... \wedge dx^n \wedge dx^1 \wedge ... \wedge dx^n$ automatically zero because of share indices?

We can generalise to manifolds, but let's concentrate on $\mathbb R^n$ for now.

2. I think we can generalise by pigeonhole principle to say for $\mathbb R^n$ if $\omega$ is a $k$-form and $\tau$ is an $l$-form and $k+l > \frac n 2$, then their wedge product must be zero. Is that correct?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: 1. yes 2. no, $k+l>n$ rather than $k+l>n/2$, as the easy $e_1\wedge e_2\neq 0$ on $\mathbb{R}^2$ shows ($n=2$, $k=l=1$)

Comment: Just remember that $\Omega^m\Bbb R^n = \{0\}$ whenever $m>n$ because, as you said, you are forced to repeat at least one index.